# Movie about a hero on a bike with a laser gun who saves a village from gangsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I'm trying to find a movie that I watched around beginning of the 90's. I remember a few scenes of the movie but cannot find it on the net.

The movie starts with the hero on a bike traveling in a desert. He then spots something moving on the road side. When he reaches it he find a man laying on the ground with his legs "eaten". The half-man asks for water then he asks to die. The hero gives him water then shots him.

The hero also has a kind of laser gun that grills an animal with one single shot.

He continues traveling and finds a small village, where the inhabitants are frequently terrified by a gangster travelling on bikes and modified cars kind of like *Mad Max*.

In the movie there is also a military commander who survives an airplane crash and starts to believe after that that he has the right to give life or remove it from whoever he wants. The commander builds a kind of a control room in a cave and manages the village from there.

Around the village, there is also a tribe of some kind of cannibals who also was spreading terror in the village. They seem to be the ones who attacked the man in the first scene.

So the hero saves the village from all these things and continues his jounrey on his bike.

Comment: One of these? http://whatculture.com/film/20-mad-max-rip-offs-you-need-to-see

Comment: I'm assuming "bike" means motorcycle, not bicycle....

Answer (score 2):

The movie is *[Steel Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Frontier)* (1995) starring Joe Lara

> In the year 2019, a gang of bandits called the "United Regime" invade the town of New Hope. They are led by General Quantrill (Brion James), a descendent of Confederate cavalry officer William Quantrill. A mysterious motorcycle riding gunslinger named Yuma (Joe Lara) arrives in town and joins the gang, but actually plays the thugs against each other, causing the drunken riders to shoot each other. The next morning Yuma's girlfriend Sarah kills two other gangmembers, but the Regime believes Yuma is responsible. Yuma tracks down his accusers and shoots six. He is chased by the rest of the gang to the tire refinery, but kills them all, including Quantrill's son.
>
> The sole survivor, Ackett (Bo Svenson) escapes to warn Quantrill. Most of the townsfolk flee but Sarah stays to help Yuma. Quantrill descends on the town with his entire army, only to find the road blocked by coffins filled with the bodies of his son and troops. Enraged, he shoots Ackett with a shotgun and enters the town, only to find it empty. The buildings, rigged with explosives, are detonated and most of Quantrill's army is destroyed. The remaining thugs converge on the town center and are attacked by armed townsfolk. Quantrill spots Yuma in a tower and sends his men after him. When they enter the tower Yuma abseils down and detonates a bomb hidden inside.
>
> Meanwhile, Sarah's son hides in an armored school bus which is later hijacked by Quantrill and chased by Yuma and Sarah. Yuma climbs into the bus and crashes it into a wrecked car. Quantrill and Yuma lie on the injured road, both within reach of their guns. Yuma draws first and kills Quantrill. Yuma loads Quantrill's corpse onto his bike and reveals he was a bounty hunter tasked with capturing Quantrill, before riding off into the sunset.

**Trailer**

**Whole Film**

Comment: Can you add some more information so that this answer still makes sense if the YT video breaks?